# Android misinterprets layout file

Tags: android

I have a main view that has a ListView.

I modified ***another activity's layout***, and now my application fails to start.

The error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ListView

I have this XML:

```
  <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#0000"
                      android:id="@+id/list" >
```

Another part of the same layout file:

```
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin" android:text="@string/okay"/>
```

When I use this, it shows the following:

```
View v= findViewById(R.id.list);
((Button)v)).getText(); //value: "OK", but how? It is a list, not a button, yet it works
ListView listView=(ListView) v; //this is where the error is
```

In the `R.java` I can find only 1 item named `list`. I already cleared the cache.

So the problem is: the list has the id of list yet Android resolves it as the button (which has a different id).

Can you tell me, what is going on?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why are you casting `v` here `(View)v)` when it is already a `View`? But that is the `id` of your `ListView` then you are trying to cast it to a `Button` in that same line. It's a little confusing what you expect to happen here or are trying to do.

Comment: well why are you casting a `View` from`R.id.list` that is a `ListView` to a `Button`, if you want the button you need to pull it by id

Comment: In which line are you getting the error? Also please show the full layout not only snippets so that we can find out what's going on.

Comment: Can't you all see the problem? Check the XML. There is a list with the id _list_, and I **can cast it to a Button**, without a problem, and it shows the button's text. The button has a _different id_.

Comment: your casting makes zero sense, why would you cast a view that is actually a listview to a button? why dont you pull the button the proper way if you want to get something from it

Comment: READ the post. It SHOULD be a list, yet casting to button WORKS. HOW?

Comment: well stop casting generically to `View` and cast it to what it should be a listview. if casting to a listview fails then you have something else wrong like its pulling from a different layout file than the one you think it is

Comment: Try printing the class of v: `System.out.println(v.getClass().getName());`

Comment: Did you try removing generated R.java file?

Comment: I did remove it and invalidated the cache. This is what the getClass gives me: android.widget.Button

Comment: `android.R.id.list` exists. Are you sure you are importing the correct `R` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted my computer, deleted every non-essential directory, cleared the cache, sent a quick prayer to Bill Gates, and now it works. Great architecture :)